# How to delete records from multiple table in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have a two table one is "tbl_subscription('entity_id', subscription_id, title)" another is "tbl_subs_pro('entity id''subscription_id' 'sku')" when i click on delete option from admin grid . the records will deleted from both table.
subscription id is a Foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to set `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the `subscription_id` foreign key, which will trigger that deleting a row in the parent table will delete all rows referencing the deleted record in the foreign keys table.

If you use XML declarative schema, you can use set `onDelete="CASCADE"` on your foreign key constraint in the `db_schema.xml`.

If you used `InstallSchema.php`, you can also specifiy `ON DELETE CASCADE`, by setting the `onDelete` parameter to `\Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE` in your `addForeignKey` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete it from delete controller file. Based on `entity_id`, load the model of `tbl_subscription` and delete then load model of `tbl_subs_pro` and delete it.

Let me know if you need more help.